# Can I prevent websites from disabling the context menu in Safari on macOS?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, websites, contextual-menu

More and more websites seem to disable the context menu in web browsers.

Can I prevent websites from disabling the context menu in Safari on macOS?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a site that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling the context menu"?
That when you do a right click on the page, you don't have any menu?

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé Yes, exactly. Either no menu or a different menu provided by the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a tool that brings back the context menu for Safari on all those websites that disable it. It’s aptly called [StopTheMadness ($8.99)](https://underpassapp.com/StopTheMadness/).

It also offers solutions for other browsers like Firefox, but I haven’t tested those.

> Many web sites disable user interface features in your browser that you normally expect to work. StopTheMadness ensures that those features continue to work for you in Safari and Firefox:

Comment: I can attest that I use this and it works well

Answer (score 2):

Hateful 'web designers' absue their privilege to run code on our machines that *restricts* our tools and workflows. To get around this offensive behaviour by evil people, *they* should pay us damages. Not we should pay to get back to simply standard behaviour.

Alternatives to paying this hostage money for standard behaviour of our browsers would be found in some cases by disabling JavaScript completely or with more granularity. But that doesn't always work.

Some free extensions for Safari that re-enable standard  workflows and rightclick behaviour would be:

**RightClick:**

> This is a native Safari extension.
>   **["Right Click"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/right-click/id1364038646?mt=12)** re-enables right click, select and copy on web sites.
>   You can use the context menu, select and copy on websites which disable those functions when you need. ( 1.0.3, OS X 10.11.5 or later, 64-bit processor, Mar 1, 2019, Price: Free)

[Smart Right Click:](https://dribbble.com/shots/3925321-Safari-Extensions)

> https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=cf.mattijs.smartrightclick-7G36RSR4E4
>   Enables the right click menu everywhere. Detects what you’re trying to right click and temporarily disables any elements in the way.
>   This means you'll be able to enter picture in picture mode with any video, download most images / videos and whatever else the right click menu usually has to offer.

Ultimately, Apple has to disable the ability of 'designers' to cripple Safari at the root completely. We should write that into our feedback forms we send to Apple.

Comment: Developers sometimes have to disable right click possibilities on their website to try to protect their content as much as they can!
They don't do that just to make you unhappy about it.
I think you understand the concept...
And btw, you can use the developer's tools in your browser to see the whole code and everything you'd want to see.
And it won't cost you a cent.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé This is "you have to break some eggs to make an omelette"? Your last argument exposes these shenanigangs as the BSshovelers they are. The 'content-protection' isn't viable: if it's on the net, I can get at it, somehow. So what remains is the breakage. I see the egg shells shattered & empty. But where is the omelette?

Comment: Developers don't disable right click to protect content; their bosses tell them to in the mistaken belief that it will help somehow.

Comment: @LangLangC Your absolutely right, I don't disagree with you at all, but, that's how it is, I was just pointing it out.